Woocommerce Rest Api get product by barcode custom meta field
I am using woocommerce rest api to get all the product data by making a query by sku. I want to do the same with the user field '_barcode'.
For a quick query, this works for me
$data=['sku'=>$sku];
$product= $client->get('products',$data);
How about '_barcode'?

Via Woo Rest Api. Calling is from another app by barcode. Not from same website.

I'm using woo rest api for remote call from another website. When using id or sku, no problem, but when trying to use a custom field, return me the last product entered.

Sorry, try $data = ['meta_data' => ['key' => '_barcode', 'value' => $barcode]]; (where $barcode is the barcode value)… untested.
